Do you say "her carelessness leaked into her blood" to express that her carelessness is her essence or habit?
Vietnamese people sometimes say "her carelessness leaked into her blood" (literally translated from Vietnamese) when they want to say that her carelessness is her essence or habit and it it very hard to change her.
Do you have a similar expression in English?
What about "Her carelessness runs in her veins" or something like that?
Note:
Vietnamese people say "her carelessness leaked into her blood" in their language for a reason.
People were not born with carelessness but they gradually develop that character over time.
Say, a mom is careless and her daughter gradually picks that up from the mom.
That's why we say "leak into" from the outside.
-"run/be in one's blood" is like you were born with that thing already.

Yes, runs in her veins is good.

You may also benefit from researching the word ingrained.

To augment @PeterKirkpatrick’s comment, Her carelessness became ingrained [in her] would seem a decent English approximation.

To say something is in [one's] blood is idiomatic. It suggests that something is part of your nature, something you were born with, perhaps an inherited skill or characteristic.

Surfing is in his blood

As blood runs in your veins, to say something "runs in [one's] veins" is a common alternative. We might also say that something is in a person's DNA.
You've explained that, in your language, "leaked into her blood" means that something has become part of someone's personality from an external source. Directly translated, it sounds weird in English, for at least a couple of reasons. Firstly, it doesn't really make sense as a complete metaphor - how does something 'leak' into one's blood? And where from? Things don't really leak into blood in a literal sense. 'Leak' isn't really a positive word, it suggests something is wrong. So, the whole thing sounds like a bit of a mixed metaphor. And, secondly, we have other metaphors that mean this.
When someone has picked up a skill, trait or habit by association, such as spending time with someone who has it, the saying is that it "rubbed off on them".

I spent a lot of time watching my dad in the kitchen and cooking must have rubbed off on me.

This can be used for bad habits as well as good things. I've also heard people use the scientific term 'osmosis' for this (eg "I picked up the skill by osmosis").
I would suggest using one or the other of these English idioms, as your saying, directly translated, seems like a mixed metaphor as it combines the English saying about something being in our blood (inherent) with the concept of picking it up from someone else.

"Weird"?? Vietnamese people say that in their language for a reason. People were not born with carelessness but they gradually develop that character over time. Say a mom is careless and her daughter gradually picks that up from the mom.  That's why we say "leak into".  "run/be in one's blood" is like you were born with that thing.

Three different phrases:- runs in our family, runs in our blood and runs through our veins.

@Tom Sorry for saying it sounds weird in English - it does! And you're here to learn English so I have to be honest. I'm sure we have some weird sayings of our own. But we'd call what you say a 'mixed metaphor'. How does something "leak into blood"? As a complete metaphor, it doesn't make sense. We also have the saying that something has rubbed off onto someone,which means that they picked it up by association, such as spending time with someone who does something. Your phrase sounds like a mix of these two things, and that's why it's odd.

@Tom I've tried to incorporate this into my answer, hope it helps.

Chat gpt translates it from Vietnamese and it suggests "Her carelessness runs in her veins".
